# JSP Form is picking the edited value in FireBug

Tags: java, jsp, firebug

I have a form to be submitted in a jsp file. When submit, the form uses a value which is coming from a hidden value, say id.

```
<input type="hidden" value="1234" name="Id">
```

Prior to submit, I am able to run the firebug and edit this input value to a non-numeric value (e.g abc). now when I submit the form, apparently the form picks the new value and throws error (id cant be non-numeric).

How can I solve this issue? Thanks,

Comment: Are you concerned that you users will be wanting to use firebug.  "id cant be non-numeric" is the required results isn't it?  Do you just have to server side validation?  What exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**might it's help for you 
you can set session variable for id and remove hidden field .
and get session variable where you wanted .**

**example :**

JSP Sessions

If you are programming the site, it is very helpful to be able to associate some data with each visitor.  For this purpose, "session"s can be used in JSP.

A session is an object associated with a visitor.  Data can be put in the session and retrieved from it, much like a Hashtable.  A different set of data is kept for each visitor to the site.

```
<%
   session.setAttribute( "id", yourid );
%>
<HTML>
<BODY>
<A HREF="NextPage.jsp">Continue</A>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

The SaveName.jsp saves the id in the session, and puts a link to another page, NextPage.jsp.

NextPage.jsp shows how to retrieve the saved name.

```
<HTML>
<BODY>
Hello, <%= session.getAttribute("id") %>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

If you bring up two different browsers (not different windows of the same browser), or run two browsers from two different machines, you can put one name in one browser and another name in another browser, and both names will be kept track of.